# Apportable, old keystore not working

Tags: android, ios, xcode, apportable

I have an old app that I originally wrote in Java using Eclipse. I have since recreated the app in Objective-C using Xcode. The iOS app is more stable and so I am trying to transfer it to Android using Apportable.  I have successfully created the release APK if I create a new keystore, but if I try to use the old keystore I get the error message below. I have verified that I am using the correct password. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
    BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=/Users/user.name/Dropbox/Apportable/Game\ Game/Game.keystore ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=password apportable build
....
        [339/339] Building Build/android-armeabi-release/FarmingGame/FarmingGame-release.apk
        FAILED: java -jar /Users/user.name/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/zipbuilder/zipbuilder.jar --zipalign 4 --keystore '/Users/user.name/Dropbox/Apportable/Farming Game/ConstructionKey.keystore' --storepass "$ANDROID_STOREPASS" --keyalias mykey --keypass "$ANDROID_KEYPASS" --cafe-marker -- /Users/user.name/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-release/FarmingGame/FarmingGame-release.apk /Users/user.name/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-release/FarmingGame/FarmingGame-release.apk.input_list
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.apportable.zipbuilder.JarSigner.generateSignatureBlock(JarSigner.java:138)
            at com.apportable.zipbuilder.JarSigner.signOutputJar(JarSigner.java:55)
            at com.apportable.zipbuilder.Main.main(Main.java:153)
        ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
        Error: command failed: /Users/user.name/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/ninja/ninja --no-strip-ansi-escapes -j 16 /Users/user.name/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-release/FarmingGame/FarmingGame-release.apk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are specifying the `ANDROID_KEY_NAME=...` environment variable in that build command.

The `ANDROID_KEY_NAME` should be set to the alias of the key you want to use.  To see which keys (and their alias values) are available run the following command from your Terminal app:

`keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/your/keystore.keystore`

Comment: I ran the suggested command (keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/user.name/Dropbox/Apportable/Game\ Game/Game.keystore) and it does show the keystore information.

Comment: This is essentially what it shows: Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myname
Creation date: Oct 25, 2012
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Ryan Tensmeyer
Issuer: CN=Ryan Tensmeyer
Serial number: xxxxxxxx
Valid from: Thu Oct 25 23:51:57 MDT 2012 until: Tue Aug 26 23:51:57 MDT 2262
Certificate fingerprints:
  MD5:  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
  Signature algorithm name: XXXXXXXXXXX
  Version: 3

Comment: Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: X.X.XX.XX Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX   XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX  ...(n...',gt..r.
0010: XX XX XX XX                                        ...H
]
]

Comment: When I do this is still fails: BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=/Users/user.name/Dropbox/Apportable/Farming\ Game/release.keystore ANDROID_KEY_NAME=myname  ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=password apportable build

Comment: My mistake. I was using the new keystore with the old alias. Below is the old keystore with the old alias and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=/Users/user.name/Dropbox/Apportable/Game\ Game/release.keystore ANDROID_KEY_NAME=myname  ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=password apportable build